# Is it possible to call an Action when using the [HandleError] attribute rather than the Error View?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using MVC3, C#, .NET4.

I am using the [HandleError] attribute which I set in the Global.asa.

```
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    }
```

In my web.config I have:

```
    <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="/Views/_Shared/Error.cshtml"/>
```

Is it possible to redirect to a controller action instead of directly to a view? I would like to redirect to the login page for certain errors.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

HandleError filter redirects to the Error.cshtml page in appropriate controller folder or Shared folder. It does not redirect to a controller action.

To redirect to controller action, you can create a FilterAttribute similar to [HandleError](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.handleerrorattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) that inherits from [IExceptionFilter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.iexceptionfilter%28v=vs.118%29.aspx). When the exception happens, redirect it to the appropriate controller.

Comment: Thank you for this comment. Do you have a code example please? Many thanks.